# How do I input a 'bar' for a letter, say, d?

Tags: math-mode, letters

Just like the 'bar' in the reduced Planck constant, in physics people need to use the same 'bar' across differential sign $d$ to indicate a *imperfect differential* in, say, a quasi-static process. How do I type it? For example,
[image]

Comment: With `amsmath` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`: `$\text{\dj}$` (or `$\text{\textit{\dj}}$` – probably a good idea to define a custom command…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, with a stack... which overlays a nonmath `-` upon a math `d`.  It currently does not work in smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\bard{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{.7ex}{d}{\mbox{-}\mkern-1.6mu}{O}{r}{F}{T}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$\bard Q = dU + P\, dV$
\end{document}
```

[image]